# Get dataset item from html <a> element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an  element within a table in html:

```
<td><a id="href0" href="#" data-productid="0">Product 1</a></td>
```

and i need to get the value of the "data-productid" attribute

at the moment i have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#href0').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.dataset.productid)
    return false;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a id="href0" href="#" data-productid="0">Product 1</a></td>
```

and nothing is being printed in the console.

I am using handlebars

Comment: Well actually 0 is being printed in the console here in Chrome so you likely forgot to load jQuery. there will be console errors too

Comment: Also no need to return false when you have preventDefault

Comment: jQuery is definitely loaded as i use it elsewhere for an AJAX query, even when using 'console.log($(this).attr("data-productid"));' nothing is printed in console

Comment: Then you have more than one id=href0

Comment: It is working in chrome.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to establish you are using Handlebars templating

What MIGHT then be the case is your links are inserted dynamically when you compile the handlebars.

If that is the case you need to delegate and then this question is a duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // document or the nearest STATIC container
  $(document).on('click','[data-productid]',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.dataset.productid)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a id="href0" href="#" data-productid="0">Product 1</a></td>
<td><a id="href0" href="#" data-productid="1">Product 2</a></td>
```

Comment: This does not work and i have manually checked all my IDs, is there more code that i should provide?

Comment: Yeah. If there are no errors at all then there is some conflicts perhaps with multiple jqueries. If you are desperate- my contact details are in my profile

Comment: @TBolton Please see update. I think you need to delegate

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to the `a` in the `td` at all (or even the `id` on the `a` or the `td`) -  simply apply the click handler to the `td` and have the data attribute on that so that when it is clicked - the console will log the data attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td').click(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('data-productid');
    console.log('The product id is ' +id)
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}


td {
  border:solid 1px #d4d4d4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td data-productid="1">Product 1</td>
   <td data-productid="2">Product 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td  data-productid="3">Product 3</td>
   <td  data-productid="4">Product 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you absolutely must have the `a` - then its the same as above - just applied to the different element

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let id = $(this).attr('data-productid');
    console.log('The product id is ' +id)
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}


td {
  border:solid 1px #d4d4d4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="#" data-productid="1">Product 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" data-productid="2">Product 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="#" data-productid="3">Product 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" data-productid="4">Product 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not answering the question in any shape or form. It is perfectly fine to have event handler on the link. In this case it was a simple case of delegation